# how to use regex for each line in a file in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

In a file I have the kind of line:

```
I     have lot         of spaces in      me.
```

and I replace every space by one space with this powershell code:

```
$String = "I     have lot         of spaces in      me."
while ($String.Contains("  "))
{
$String = $String -replace "  "," "}
```

the result is :

`I have lot of spaces in me.`

I would like to do that for each line in a txt file. could you give me the best way to do that?

---

Part two:

How can I replace something only when there are more than one whitespace with e.g. `;`?

The response will be:

```
;4828;toto;toto;Ticket;0112APPT
```

and not :

```
;4828;toto toto;Ticket;0112APPT
```

To be clear, I would like replace only two White-Space by the Character `;`

Comment: `Get-Content yourfile.txt | % {$_ -replace '\s+', ' '}` ?

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
is it possible to keep the while condition?

because in the following case :

4828  toto toto      Ticket                0112APPT
if I want to replace more that one space with the character ;

the response will be:

;4828;toto;toto;Ticket;0112APPT
and not :

;4828;toto toto;Ticket;0112APPT

To be clear, I would like replace only two Space by the Character ;

Kind regards

Comment: Dont write it as a comment... edit your question and append it there.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, i updated it to fit your second question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, this should do it for you (atleast in my test):

```
Get-Content yourfile.txt | % {$_ -replace '\s+', ' '}
```

**Explanation:**

`Get-Content` - Gets Content from given File

`| %` - foreach line of the content given from `Get-Content`

`$_ -replace '\s+', ' '` - `'\s+'`  stands for one or more whitespaces

---

If you want to change the content of the File with the replaced strings you can also pipe it to `Set-Content` and save it in another file:

`Get-Content yourfile.txt | % {$_ -replace '\s+', ' '} | Set-Content yourOutputFile.txt`

> If you want to write to the same file in the pipe, take a look at: [Why you dont do it!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51272251/ps-script-is-exporting-an-empty-csvs/51275716#51275716)

---

Given your second question to ignore single whitespaces in the regex, this is how you would go if you want to replace more than one whitspace with `;`.

This will not replace spots with a single whitespace:

```
Get-Content yourfile.txt | % {$_ -replace '\s\s+', ';'}
```

Comment: Many Thanks Paxz it works fine
to your tricks I'd also add the rewrite of the file Like that

Get-Content yourfile.txt | % {$_ -replace '\s+', ' '} | Set-Content yourfile.txt

Comment: @LudovicHertzog Added it to the answer.
Remember to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer that you found most helpful.

Comment: @Paxz I think that using `Get-Content | ... | Set-Content` to the same file is not very good practice due to possible data loss (cannot find the link right now)

Comment: @robdy for the example I "set content" to the same file, but in my script I edit a new One

Comment: Yea, I just wanted to suggest improvement to the answer (other people might look at that in the future and blindly copy it).

Comment: @robdy yeah I changed it now. If you somehow manage to find the link again, I would love to read it. I can imagine why it would be bad practice, but couldn't find specific explanations on a quick google.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
(Get-Content '.\TextDocument.txt' -Raw) -replace ' +', ' '
```

Note that using `\s` instead of an actual space in the RegEx is an option, but it will remove [not just spaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#WhitespaceCharacter), but such things as tabs and, more crucially, end of line characters.