# Replace characters with incrementing value

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to figure out how to replace a certain string that repeats itself multiple time in a txt file with an incrementing value.

What I try to achieve is the following:

I have multiple HTML links in a table, each of the links have the exact same ending i.e.: XYZ

I want to change XYZ to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and so on... using PowerShell.

```
(Get-Content c:\temp\test.txt).replace('XYZ', 'MyValue') |
    Set-Content c:\temp\test.txt
```

It is the 'MyValue' part of using an incrementing number for each replacement I'm not sure how to achieve it.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: be aware of using `Get-Content | .... | Set-Content` to the same file due to [possible data loss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51275716/9902555)! It doesn't apply to reading file in a subexpression/grouping expression as you did, but be aware of it in the future (as a best practice). Credits to [@Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) for clarification.

---

**Solution:**

You can define callback function to [`[Regex]::Replace (String, String, MatchEvaluator)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
$global:counter = 0
$content = (Get-Content c:\temp\test.txt)

# Below can be used to verify it's working correctly instead of creating a file
# $content = "aXYZ","bXYZ","cXYZ","dXYZ","eXYZ"

$content | % {[Regex]::Replace($_, 'XYZ', {return $global:counter += 1}) } | Set-Content c:\temp\test.txt
```

Output will be:

```
a1
b2
c3
d4
e5
```

---

**Explanation:**

The parameters you pass to `Replace` are as follows:

1. The string to search for a match.
2. The regular expression pattern to match.
3. A custom method that examines each match and returns either the original matched string or a replacement string.

The custom method increments the counter each time the regex is matched. Unfortunately, for some reason, it requires you to use global variable scope which is in general not the best practice if not needed (as mentioned by [@Paxz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6404133/paxz) in the comments).

As [@TessellatingHeckler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478656/tessellatingheckler) found out, the first version of solution used `Replace` on `$content` variable which resulted in removing all newlines. You have to use `Foreach-Object` (or `%` as its alias) to do the replacing in each single line.

Comment: The same can be achieved without the `global` scope. Using a global scope, where it is not explicit needed is a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Paxz! Yea, I know that we should avoid that but I wasn't able (yet) to achieve that without it this time. Can you suggest?

Comment: Yeah I tested it wrong, seems like i really needs another scope (that kinda makes me sad...).

Comment: Incorrect output, you've implicitly joined all the lines with a space into one string. Now the file has no newlines.

Comment: Nice catch, fixed.

Comment: Okay, I'm in love with this community wow. Thank you so much for curing my headache I was having with this !

Comment: You're welcome! Please remember to mark the answer which helped you as accepted (see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Writing to the same file is not an issue if you read the file in a subexpression/grouping expression as the OP does.

Comment: Thx @AnsgarWiechers, clarified in my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Same as @robdy answer, but without the `global` scope refference:

```
# Simulation of Get-Content
$content = "aXYZ","bXYZ","cXYZ","dXYZ","eXYZ"

$i = 0
$result = $content.ForEach({
    $i++
    $_ -replace 'XYZ', $i
})

$result | Out-File -FilePath "$env:TEMP\test.txt" -Encoding utf8 -NoClobber
```

We're basically looping over the content of the file and replace the string `XYZ` with the number. Then we save that in to a new variable, which is later used to write the new content to the file.